# How to force Monotouch AOT Compiler to see a nested generic method?

Tags: xamarin.ios, servicestack, aot

I've had to jump through hoops, but I've almost managed to get `ServiceStack` working on iOS with `Monotouch` in my project. One runtime `JIT` exception is holding out:

```c#
System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer:GetWriteFn<int> ()' while running with --aot-only.
```

The offending code is quite simple:

```c#
   internal WriteObjectDelegate GetWriteFn<T>()
    {
        return JsonWriter<T>.WriteFn();
    }
```

As a test, I modified the SS code to make the internal methods and types public and included the following in the startup code of my project (to actually get called).

```c#
var ick = ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonWriter<int>.WriteFn();
var erk = ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonTypeSerializer.Instance.GetWriteFn<int>();
```

This still doesn't alert the AOT for some reason, I get the exception when the code above executes! Is this because the generic parameter is a value type? Or is it because these are static classes and methods? How can I force Monotouch to AOT the methods above?

The SS code in question is in JsonTypeSerializer.cs and JsonWriter.Generic.cs at:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/Json

Comment: This looks strange. Can you file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a test case?

Comment: Having the same problem, the only way to serialize a list of ints is: var serializedData = "["+string.Join(",", Ids.ToArray())+"]";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some generic [limitations](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations) in monotouch now. I think you should check your code to one of them.